# Error messages when doing regression in SPSS

Tags: regression, spss, ordinal-data, error

I need to do a number of regressions in SPSS but keep getting error messages. For example -

"There are X cells (i.e., dependent variable levels by combinations of predictor variable values) with zero frequencies."

and

"The log-likelihood value is practically zero. There may be a complete separation in the data. The maximum likelihood estimates do not exist."

Example of one of the regressions I am trying to carry out -

I'm examining carcass damage in pigs, specifically, the effect of injuries that occurred on farm on the injuries visible on the carcass. I want to predict skin lesion severity at the abattoir (absent, mild, moderate, severe) from skin lesion severity on farm (absent, mild, moderate, severe) and the number of weeks the animals had moderate or severe skin lesions (0 weeks, 1 week, 2 weeks, 3 weeks). I want to do an ordinal regression on this data.

Could somebody explain to me in simple terms how to avoid the "zero frequencies" error message and other error messages?

Update - I have researched this online and now understand why I am getting the "zero frequencies" message. If there are some zero frequencies does this mean that I can't do a  regression on the data? Is there an alternative?

Comment: Are you doing logistic regression, or linear regression, or something else?

Comment: For the example above I'm doing ordinal regression